# Flex/Bison based lexer/parser for C language

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, ansi-c

Is there a simple lexer/parser for C language or a subset of it which is based on Flex/Bison?

I have found some open source parsers for C (TCC, LCC, ...) but none of them are based on bison.

Comment: Adding a comment stating the reason of downvote would be much more useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/kranthikiran01/subc-compiler) is an implementation of a compiler for a subset of C using bison/flex.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [C11 grammar](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) for YACC (a predecessor of Bison), it should work with Bison (maybe some tweaks will be needed).

GCC used to be based on Bison a long ago. GCC 3.4 source code contains a [file](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/c-parse.in;h=66d27ac0322f335aed8a3302522bcf19ffc9d1bf;hb=359e576cf4a70392fda974114498ba451310ab05) with C grammar.